# Overlay 2 x axis on a line graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Here's my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/msuatp90/3/

Basically I want Revenue and Past Revenue to be overlaid so that I can compare one period against the previous period. It will always have the same ticks for each.

Same thing for the profit data, I'd like Profit and Past Profit to overlay.

All 4 data sets will have the exact same number of ticks every time.  But for some reason, they're not overlaying, they're continuing one after another.

The tooltips seem to be working fine though.

Here's the complete code I have right now:

```
let startGraph = function() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
  let chart = new Chart(canvas.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Revenue',
          data: {
            "2023-03-01": 250,
            "2023-03-02": 488,
            "2023-03-03": 358,
            "2023-03-04": 255,
            "2023-03-05": 895
          },
          borderColor: '#ff6384',
          xAxisID: 'x',
        },
        {
          label: 'Profit',
          data: {
            "2023-03-01": 125,
            "2023-03-02": 156,
            "2023-03-03": 195,
            "2023-03-04": 98,
            "2023-03-05": 466
          },
          borderColor: '#36a2eb',
          xAxisID: 'x',
        },
        {
          label: 'Past Revenue',
          data: {
            "2023-02-24": 280,
            "2023-02-25": 456,
            "2023-02-26": 665,
            "2023-02-27": 288,
            "2023-02-28": 499
          },
          borderColor: '#fa829b',
          xAxisID: 'x1',
        },
        {
          label: 'Past Profit',
          data: {
            "2023-02-24": 125,
            "2023-02-25": 198,
            "2023-02-26": 265,
            "2023-02-27": 101,
            "2023-02-28": 221
          },
          borderColor: '#76c1f5',
          xAxisID: 'x1',
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 0,
          hoverRadius: 0,
          hitRadius: 3,
        },
        line: {
          borderWidth: 2,
        },
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      interaction: {
        intersect: false,
        mode: 'index',
      },
      stacked: false,
      scales: {
        y: {
          ticks: {
            display: true,
            beginAtZero: true,
          }
        },
        x: {
          position: 'bottom',
          ticks: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        x1: {
          position: 'top',
          ticks: {
            display: false,
          },
          grid: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
          labels: {
            boxWidth: 8,
            boxHeight: 8,
            useBorderRadius: true,
            borderRadius: 3,
            usePointStyle: false,
            pointStyleWidth: 0,
            padding: 7,
            font: {
              size: 11
            }
          }
        },
      },
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the `x` and `x1` axes ticks, you'll see what the problem is: both x axes are are categorical, not time axes, which means that the date strings are treated as simple strings and not interpreted as dates. This might work for you since the dates are all of the same interval (1 day), but it is still dangerous as they not sorted and there's no guarantee that they will be in order.

So, to solve the issue and make the chart display safer, I'd parse the dates and transform them into a date-sorted array of the form

```
[{x:timestamp1, y: value1}, {x: timestamp2, y: value2},...]
```

Here's a function that does that for your `date` format:

```js
function parseDateIndexed(data){
    return Object.entries(data).
        map(([s, f])=>({x: Date.parse(s), y: f, s})).
        sort(({x:t1},{x:t2})=>t1-t2);
}
```

I also saved the original date in string format under `s`, because it can prove useful when formatting, for instance the tooltip.

If you don't want to display the dates, you can make axes `"linear"`, as in the example below, where the only tricky part is formatting the tooltip title. The same technique can be applied to format the axis labels, but you can also opt for declaring the type of the x axes as `"time"` and using an [adapter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters), like [chartjs-adapter-date-fns](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns).

```js
function parseDateIndexed(data){
    return Object.entries(data).
    map(([s, f])=>({x: Date.parse(s), y: f, s})).
    sort(({x:t1},{x:t2})=>t1-t2);
}

let startGraph = function() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
    let chart = new Chart(canvas.getContext('2d'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Revenue',
                data: parseDateIndexed({
                    "2023-03-01": 250,
                    "2023-03-02": 488,
                    "2023-03-03": 358,
                    "2023-03-04": 255,
                    "2023-03-05": 895
                }),
                borderColor: '#ff6384',
                xAxisID: 'x',
            },
                {
                    label: 'Profit',
                    data: parseDateIndexed({
                        "2023-03-01": 125,
                        "2023-03-02": 156,
                        "2023-03-03": 195,
                        "2023-03-04": 98,
                        "2023-03-05": 466
                    }),
                    borderColor: '#36a2eb',
                    xAxisID: 'x',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Past Revenue',
                    data: parseDateIndexed({
                        "2023-02-24": 280,
                        "2023-02-25": 456,
                        "2023-02-26": 665,
                        "2023-02-27": 288,
                        "2023-02-28": 499
                    }),
                    borderColor: '#fa829b',
                    xAxisID: 'x1',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Past Profit',
                    data: parseDateIndexed({
                        "2023-02-24": 125,
                        "2023-02-25": 198,
                        "2023-02-26": 265,
                        "2023-02-27": 101,
                        "2023-02-28": 221
                    }),
                    borderColor: '#76c1f5',
                    xAxisID: 'x1',
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 0,
                    hoverRadius: 0,
                    hitRadius: 3,
                },
                line: {
                    borderWidth: 2,
                },
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            interaction: {
                intersect: false,
                mode: 'index',
            },
            stacked: false,
            scales: {
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        display: true,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                },
                x: {
                    type:"linear",
                    position: 'bottom',
                    bounds: 'data',
                    ticks: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                },
                x1: {
                    type:"linear",
                    position: 'top',
                    bounds: 'data',
                    ticks: {
                       display: false,
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawOnChartArea: false,
                    },
                },
            },
            plugins: {
                tooltip:{
                    callbacks:{
                        title(items){
                            const dates = items.map(o=>o.raw.s);
                            const d1 = dates[0], d2 = dates[dates.length-1];
                            const ad = (d1 === d2) ? d1 : [d1, d2];
                            return ad.join(' / ')
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 8,
                        boxHeight: 8,
                        useBorderRadius: true,
                        borderRadius: 3,
                        usePointStyle: false,
                        pointStyleWidth: 0,
                        padding: 7,
                        font: {
                            size: 11
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    startGraph();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-t41WshQCxr9T3SWH3DBZoDnAT9gfVLtQS+NKO60fdAwScoB37rXtdxT/oKe986G0BFnP4mtGzXxuYpHrMoMJLA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: do you know why the lines do not line up?  It seems like Past Profit starts after the Profit line, and ends after it as well.  Same thing with the Revenue lines. Then if I add like 30 days worth of data, the mismatch of the lines becomes even greater.

Comment: @zen I added `bounds: 'data'` to both x axes options - it forces the axes to start exactly from the first and end at exactly the last date. Please see if it works for more data too.

Comment: thanks yea that seems to have fixed it. It also fixed another issue I had which was extra padding around the axis, and the padding property did not have any effect on that.